# AIR cert on AIR for iphone

Tags: iphone, flash, air, certificate, thawte

I have adobe air cert from thawte , I am a casual flash game developer, I was trying to package my game to iphone app but stuck with iphone certificate. As a flash/air developer , I suppose AIR cert should work here? but I m not sure because I know apple is strict.

So in my scenario do I need to buy another cert from apple? or my existing air cert should work?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a .p12 and a provisioning profile. In short, yes you will need a apple developer account. They also go into detail, when you sign up, on how to create these assets. If you are on PC there will be extra steps and you can look it up on how.